# How to output list of legal argument when input is illegal?

Tags: python, metaprogramming, decorator

I need to implement lots of function which have case selection like this:

```
def foo1(bar1):
    if bar1 == 'A':
        do something
    elif bar1 == 'B':
        do something
    elif ...
    ...
    else:
        raise ValueError('legal input of bar1 should be {}'.format(list_of_bar))

def foo2(bar2):
    if bar2 == 'A':
        do something
    elif bar2 == 'B':
        do something
    elif ...
    ...
    else:
        raise ValueError('legal input of bar2 should be {}'.format(list_of_bar))

'''
```

According to "Don't repeat it yourself", is there any way to avoid repeating the final step of raise error and print the list of correct argument? I thought a decorator might do this, but not sure how to make it. Thanks in advance.

## update

I implemented it myself with inspect module. But I still hope can get some advice or better solutions

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps
import re

def test_none(func):
    _code = inspect.getsource(func)
    _list = re.findall(r'if (\w+) == (\w+)', _code)
    assert all(_list[0][0] == name for name, case in _list)
    _arg = _list[0][0]
    _case = tuple(case for name, case in _list)

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        results = func(*args, **kwargs)
        if results is None:
            raise ValueError(
                    'Legal value of \'{arg}\' should be anyone of {case}'.format(
                    arg=_arg, case=_case))
        return results
    return wrapper

@test_none
def foo(bar):
    if bar == 0:
        return 1
    elif bar == 1:
        return 2
```

Test example:

```
foo(3)
ValueError: Legal value of 'bar' should be anyone of ('0', '1')
```

Comment: You're looking for something that maps `"A"` to `do something`, `"B"` to `do something else`, etc. In other words, you want a dict.

Comment: But with a dictionary, I also need to do the final raise Error and printing step, which is I really want to avoid by a decorator or other "black magic".

Answer (score 1):

I generally find that the 'many cases' pattern is more clearly expressed with dictionaries.

I'll assume here that for each case we have a different function we want to call, but the pattern works if each value is just an integer you want to return, or any other object.

e.g. The `CASES` dictionary clearly and compactly signals to the reader of the code the different cases.

```
CASES = {
    'A': do_something,
    'B': do_something_else,
    ...
}

def foo(bar):
    if bar not in CASES:
        raise ValueError('legal input of bar should be {}'.format(list_of_bar))

    # do stuff
    CASES[bar]()
```

An alternative is to use the 'ask for forgiveness, not permission' pattern. I find in this particular case it's not as clear as the above though.

```
def foo(bar):
    try:
        func = CASES[bar]
    except KeyError:
        raise ValueError(...)
    # do stuff
    func()
```

or use the dictionary `.get` method as another way, but again I think it's not as clear as the first way for this particular scenario.

```
def foo(bar):
    func = CASES.get(bar)
    if func is None:
         raise ValueError(...)
    # do stuff
    func()
```

Comment: I like all of these responses - and think there are good use cases for each paradigm. Great job!

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But if I have lots of similar function foo to define, there is also quite a lot redundancy of the overall structure. I was wondering if there is a way to take the function "foo" in without the raise error step, then spit out a new function with the final step.

Answer (score 1):

Use a dictionary to map the possible inputs to actions, something like this:

```
def foo(bar):
    def a():
        print('a():')

    def b():
        print('b():')

    def c():
        print('c():')

    actions = {'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c}
    if bar in actions:
        actions[bar]()
    else:
        raise ValueError('legal input of bar should be {}'.format(sorted(actions.keys())))
```

Demo:

```
>>> foo('A')
a():
>>> foo('Z')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "x.py", line 15, in foo
    raise ValueError('legal input of bar should be {}'.format(sorted(actions.keys())))
ValueError: legal input of bar should be ['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Comment: Yes dictionary works quite well in this case. Sorry if I didn't express it clearly, but what I need is to avoid the final "raise ValueError" step. Because I need a bunch of different function having this similar structure, I was thinking about is there a way to bypass the repeated raise Error and printing step. I thought this may need some metaprogramming.